# Is creating a WCF service host an expensive process?

Tags: wcf

I want to host multiple WCF services in windows service but I am unsure if hosting multiple WCF services is an expensive process?  Can someone please guide?

Comment: What is the context of your question?  Do you mean expensive from a resouce perspective?  In other words, are you asking should you split your service operations between two services or create a single service that encapsulates all service operations?

Comment: exactly that, i want to know if there is any problem in breaking my service into multiple services and hosting each service individually?

Comment: In that case, the response from ChrisBint below is accurate.  Generally speaking, from a resource point of view, there's no reason not to do this.  Plus, in terms of maintainability, splitting things out to multiple services will be better than trying to make one service that is just does everything.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the complexity of the service itself, but generally, they are not resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

It will also depends of the **number of connected clients** and **requests** you will get.

Comment: I don't think you have any connected clients and requests yet, when you're just constructing the service host ....

Answer (score 0):

The rule is very simple here. You need to decompose your system requirements into the right level of granularity that minimizes the cost of implementation versus the cost of integration. Too many services and your integration costs will suffer. Too few services and your implementation costs will suffer. My personal experience is that if any service has more than 10 methods you really need to start looking into your design and the methodology you have used to design it like that. Also please note that services with too many methods do not scale that well neither.